# How would you strip something form an active model serialize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I am looking to use active model serialize on a model called roles, which spits back the roles and that roles permissions. How ever, I want to tell Active Model Serializer that if the role name is Administrator you should **never** include it in the json of roles returned.

So if I do a `show` or a `index` action on roles through an api call, I should never see `Administrator` in the returned result.

Right now this is all I have for role serialize:

```
class RoleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :role
end
```

Would I do it here or in the controller for index and show? and if so what would I do?

Answer (score 0):

The job of an Active Model serializer is not to select which records should and should not be returned in the json. For this you want to use a scope or at least a `where` statement.

You could probably also skip the custom serializer, and just pass the attributes you want to `to_json`.

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :without_adminstrators, -> { where('role <> "Administrator"') }

end

class RolesController < ApplicationController

  def non_administrator
    Role.without_adminstrators.to_json(only: [:id, :role])
  end

end
```

Comment: Could I add to the index, for example: `@roles = Roles.where.not(name: 'Administrator')` and then use the serialize as intended? and then do something similar for the show?